# How can I get a c + + program to read in a text file named by the user?

Tags: c++, input, ifstream

This is the code I am attempting to use:

```
//Have the user input the file name that they want to read
cout << "Enter name of file: ";
cin >> recordName;

//Create the object that the file will be read into
ifstream records;

//Open file for reading
records.open(recordName);
```

The text file is just a list of people's names and pay rates. The code will not compile as is and I do not know why it will not read a string as a text file name.

Comment: What errors you are getting ?

Comment: If that's the entire code, you are missing the inclusion of a couple of headers and you need a `main` function.

Comment: Always post the compiler error so we don't need to guess.

Comment: Is this your code, or did you find this somewhere also?

Comment: "The code will not compile" is not a problem description. You have the error information (and message) right in front of you on your screen (which we can't see from here). There is absolutely no excuse for not including it in your post. Please [edit] to do so. If you want us to help you, you need to **provide the information we can use to do so**.

Comment: Its just a snippet of code, the compiler error reads:
C:\Classes\C++\Lab10-1.cpp|33|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::string&)'|

Comment: @Craig: Exactly, that line tells you there is no function std::ifstream that takes a parameter of type std::string.  std::ifstream takes a const char*.  You must cast it first as in MarJamRobs answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
cout << "Enter filename: ";
std::string filename;
cin >> filename;
cout << endl;

// Open file
ifstream file(filename.c_str());
```

This is not my code, but it will do what you want.
Sourced: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/1007/

And of course, you need headers if you don't have them, I assume that is just a snippet though.

Alternatively, in "C++11 `std::basic_ifstream::open` can accept `std::string`" (Thanks P0W)

Comment: Since `C++11` `std::basic_ifstream::open` can accept `std::string`

Comment: Just to be clear:  @MarJamRob is casting the std::string into a const char *, which is the accepted type of the std::ifstream function.